# Get Logcat of Particular Application

Tags: android, logcat

Can Anybody tell me how we can got the Logcat of particular application. I want to be create an application in which user choose the name of application e.g. radio, Facebook, Navigation etc. After choosing it user click on the button. After clicking on the button the log of the chosen application can be got in file or in any form...!!!

Thanx in Advance

Comment: logcat isn't individual to each application, there's just one logcat and every application uses it...at most you can grep through it, provided that application uses a keyword for each log entry (which is unlikely)

Comment: But when we want to get the log of radio then by the help of this command we can grep the log of radio...



adb logcat -b radio

Comment: [See here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/logcat.html) i don't think it does what you think it does.

Comment: I already see it, and by the help of it, I develop the application but there are some little mistake, I can't get actual solution...!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
   String baseCommand = "logcat -v time";

        try {
              Process logReaderProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(baseCommand);
              BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
               new InputStreamReader(logReaderProcess.getInputStream()));

               while ((line =bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        log.append(line); // here readLine() returns null
                      }

        }
        catch (IOException e1) {
                  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                  e1.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: user chosen application? means?

Comment: Means I make a spinner in which given the name of some Application e.g. Radio, Facebook, Navigation etc. Whenever user choose any one application and click on the button then send the log of that application via mail...

Comment: do you want to filter by application name?

Comment: If any application didn't launch then how can you get that application's logcat?

Comment: @user370305 When that application was there then this application will be work

And I want to be make this application for any project in which all given application will be exist...