# Using GREP command to filter logcat in Android

Tags: android, grep, android-logcat

I use the following code to read the logcat in Android.

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -v time");
```

Since the logcat file size is large, I have to filter the logcat messages. So I used the following code to filter logcat.

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -v time | grep -v -E \"(libloc|RPC)\"");
```

where (libloc|RPC) are tags.

But Grep code is not working in Android. Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got the answer. I have to use the file name to use the grep command.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -v time -f "+logCatFile.getAbsolutePath()+ " libloc:S RPC:S")
```

Answer (score 1):

If grep is not working (I use regexp on the logcat UI directly) then you can make your own grep reading line by line.

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -v time");
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
  if(line.matches("^.*(libloc|RPC).*$")) {
     //code
  }
}
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8178793/get-logcat-of-particular-application?answertab=votes#tab-top)