# Android Native - how to intercept or filter logcat

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm compiling in debug mode a certain `.so` in the Android-Native layer which by default outputs to the default logging file.

However, I do not want this data to be saved to the logs in the first place because it will overwhelm the logging file; I plan on streaming it off of the device.

**POSSIBLE SOLUTIONS**

1. Modify the `.so` code to output the debug info to NOT the logging file.
   Definitely the most straightforward way but I'd prefer not to do this since this'll require modification of the `.so`. I agree this should be trivial modification but I have a requirement to modify the `.so` as little as possible.
2. Is there a way to create an alias for a file, pipe all writes to it through my app (like `tee`) and selectively allow writes to the real file?
3. Is there a built-in `logcat` filtering tool that can do this filtering for me with some regexs?

Comment: `adb logcat -v threadtime MySpammyTag:E` ?  That would filter out anything tagged with `MySpammyTag` with a severity below `ANDROID_LOG_ERROR` (use `S` if you want to silence that tag completely).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the first solution is indeed the trivial and the better one - since it remains in the code unlike the logcat filtering that might get deleted.
If the requirement is to modify the `.so` as little as possible, there is no real problem - you modify the **code** using `#ifdef` for debug only, so the **code** changes for debug mode, but the generated `.so` for release does not change. This will give you a very good control - but in case you have a lot of 'special' debug code, it will make your code a little ugly...

**Edit:**
If you want to write to you own log, you can run `logcat` using `Runtime` class, with your own parameters - look here: [Using GREP command to filter logcat in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17448912/using-grep-command-to-filter-logcat-in-android).

Regarding the logcat filtering - you can use regex in the filtering in Android Studio. You have a 'regex' check box next to the input box. See here for more details: [How to exclude certain messages by TAG name using Android adb logcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511433/how-to-exclude-certain-messages-by-tag-name-using-android-adb-logcat)

Comment: This solution doesn't prevent from the data being saved to the logfile; it prevents me from seeing.

Comment: @Adrian I merely referred to your point, you wrote #1 as a possible solution, you did not say you do not know how to do this one. I'm updating my answer to cover that as well.